# ASCII symbol for Pipe delimiter

Tags: java, xml, spring

```
<!-- (&#9;) is encoded tab character -->
<property name="delimiter" value="&#9;" />
```

What will be the value for (|)PIPE ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: Um, "|"? It's fine as it is - there's no need to represent it in an entity.

Comment: For list of html characters.. http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/symbols.html

Comment: Before you submit a question to StackOverflow, please try typing the title of the question into Google. That way you can save us all a lot of time. Incidentally, this question has nothing to do with any of the three tags you have assigned to it. Downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII value of `|` is `&#124;`

See [this link](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII value of '|' is is 124.